# how to make input to except only from 0.0 to 5.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new in javascript and don't know what to in this case please provide me solution

```
<input type="text" name="technical" maxlength="3" id="numa" onKeyUp="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 5)" class="input-text persent managementskill" value="<?=set_value('technical',$this->input->post('technical'))?>" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function minmax(value, min, max) 
{

    if(parseInt(value) < min || isNaN(value)) 
        return 0; 
    else if(parseInt(value) > max) 
        return 5; 
    else return value;

}
</script>
```

This is my code is working fine for the first entry of input it will not except after 5 but I want if we enter 5.1 then it automatically converts that num to 5.0 want this to except only 0.0 to 5.0 
what to do in my function  please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in simple way you can just `return '5.0';`
just try it.

Comment: <li><span class="users_check">
 <input type="checkbox" name="user_name" value="<?=$user['user_id']?>" ></span><p><?= $user['f_name']?> </p></li>
 
 during insert as i select it select but how to make it selected becoz i have too many checkbox it only when i checked at that time display checked click on submit it display username required
how to make it selected

Comment: please show your code .. i am not able to find out the exact issue.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="user_name" value="<?=$user['user_id']?>" >

Comment: want to make it selected during insert as in codigniter if i use required condition it doesnot make it select after i click on submit

Answer (score 3):

0.0, 5.0, 5.1 are not integer values, these are floating point values. Simply use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseFloat()` instead. `parseInt()` will convert `5.1` to `5`.

Also `isNaN()` should be checked before parsing the value.

So your function code would look something like this,

```
function minmax(value, min, max) 
{

    if(isNaN(value) || parseFloat(value) < min) 
        return 0; 
    else if(parseFloat(value) > max) 
        return max; 
    else return value;

}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp